# Is the word "mechanics" singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number

Is the word "mechanics" singular or plural? For example, should I say that the skin mechanics vary or varies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what skin mechanics are, but they are plural. Swing mechanics in golf, as in, all the things one does that contribute to a good swing, are plural.

"The skin mechanics vary [from person to person]."

Comment: But *skin mechanics was my special interest at university*?

Comment: Quantum mechanics is a fundamental branch of physics. Quantum mechanics explains the way a photon can interfere with itself.

Comment: I strongly recommend you look at the duplicate which @choster spotted. There is some very good material there, on this subject.

Comment: 'Skin mechanics was my special interest at university' refers to the (singular) subject of skin mechanics. As does the next comment, 'Quantum Mechanics'. If you're talking about a single subject of study, it's singular. If you're talking about several mechanics that contribute to skin, it's plural.